# why this code is wrong ? How does 'recur' work?

Tags: clojure

I don't know why the code below is wrong:

```
(defn factorial [n]
  (loop [n n
         acc 1]
    (if (zero? n)
      acc
      (recur (* acc n)(dec n)))))

 (= 1 (factorial 1))
```

How does `recur` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments to the `recur` are the wrong way round.

- `n` should become `(dec n)`
- `acc` should become `(* acc n)`

So it should be

```
(recur (dec n) (* acc n))
```

---

We can recast the given algorithm to see what's going on inside it.

If we represent the pair of arguments as a vector, the function that generates the next pair is

```
(fn [[n acc]] [(* acc n) (dec n)])
```

We can generate the endless sequence of possible pairs for a given `no`by applying `iterate` to the function above, starting with `[no 1]`.

```
(fn [no]
  (iterate (fn [[n acc]] [(* acc n) (dec n)]) [no 1]))
```

Applying this to `1` generates

```
([1 1] [1 0] [0 0] [0 -1] ...)
```

We stop at element 2, the first with an initial `0`, returning the other `0`.

If we put the arguments the right way round, we can get the proper `factorial` thus:

```
(defn factorial [no]
  ((comp second first)
         (drop-while
           (comp not zero? first)
           (iterate (fn [[n acc]] [(dec n) (* acc n)]) [no 1]))))
```

This returns the `second` element of the `first` pair in the sequence with a zero `first` (Duh!).

Hopelessly overcomplicated for normal use, but does it work?

```
=> (map factorial (range 6))
(1 1 2 6 24 120)
```

Yes.